# How to get only the unique values from 5 different ranges and the delete the repeated values?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 5 columns that are updated based on the inputs from 5 different users i,e all values that User 1 inputs in his `userform` are updated in Column 1
all values that User 2 inputs in his `userform` are updated in Column 2 and so on.However , when this happens there is a possibility that 2 or more users might enter the same value.I want to loop through all the 5 columns and keep only the values that do not repeat in any of the column.

Eg: Please check the image(Question.jpg) for reference
[image: Question.jpg]

In the image a lot of values are repeated in columns of user 2 , user 3 , user 4 and user 5.
I want to delete the repeated values and keep only the unique values in the respective ranges.
Please watch the 2nd image(Solution.jpg) on how the output should look like.
[image: Solution.jpg]

I tried the code given below but it works only for 1 column and i cannot figure out a way to make it work for all 5 columns.Also , is there a better way to do so?

```
lastrow1 = wsh.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 6 To lastrow1
id = wsh.Range("I" & i).Value



    lastrow2 = wsh.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For j = 6 To lastrow2
        id2 = wsh.Range("J" & j).Value



            If id = id2 Then
                wsh.Range("J" & j).Value = ""
            Else
                 wsh.Range("J" & j).Value = wsh.Range("J" & j).Value
            End If


        Next j
Next i
```

Comment: How would the ownership logic go though? Will you always start with User1 and go down and right to the other users? Or it doesn't matter which user gets which ED, as long as there are no repetitions?

Comment: @Jerome_Montino It'll start with User 1 and go down and right.The first person among the 5 to update the ED in his userform will have his ED's in the 1st column i,e User 1 column in this case and so on. If this doesn't work then , as long as there aren't any repetitions that shall work too but the first case would be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This will work:**

**Note:**

- Make sure to add the Reference `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`. Tools > References
- Change the Range in the Code as Per your Sheet And Range

**Code:**

```
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim val_removed as String

With ActiveSheet.Range("D1:F9") 'Change the Range

For i = 1 To .Columns.Count
    For j = 1 To .Rows.Count

        If Not dict.Exists(.Cells(j, i).Text) Then
            dict.Add .Cells(j, i).Text, .Cells(j, i)
        Else
            val_removed = val_removed & "," & .Cells(j, i).Value
            .Cells(j, i).Value = ""
        End If

    Next            
Next

Set dict = Nothing

End With

Msgbox val_Removed
```

**`Scripting.Dictionary`** is my favorite to Remove Duplicates.

---

**Demo:**

[image]

Comment: Hi! I am wondering is there a way to save the values that are being cleared in a variant and display all of them at once in a message box?

Comment: Yes ... You can do that.  Updated the code accordingly @Sw1tch